# Python Regex parsing with HTML inside HTML cells

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

Edit: I noticed that this has been downvoted as a duplicate, however, it is not, as a the duplicate solution involves the usage of beautifulsoup for parsing. I understand that beautifulsoup is a better solution to this problem, but for the sake of learning, I have been trying to use Regex.

I'm a novice with Regex and am working on a Python-based Regex parser for HTML tables. So far, I have managed to generate patterns that correctly parse normal rows, cells, and headers, but am looking to modify my Regex to accommodate for HTML within cells and headers. Essentially, I am looking to leave HTML code that's within a larger cell unevaluated, doing something like this:

```
found = re.findall(isHeader,"<th>Student</th> Name</th>")
found = "Student</th> Name"
```

After doing some research, I am trying to approach the problem using a look-ahead:

```
isHeader = r'<th\s*>([\S\s]*?)</th\s*>(?!(?:</th\s*>))'
```

This Regex is an attempt at isolating a string that begins with "`<th>`", and ends with "`</th>`", provided there are no more "`</th>`"s in that same pattern before the next pattern begins. The pattern successfully isolates "proper" headers (with no `</th>`s in the header itself), but fails to parse "improper" headers correctly, stopping the string at the first `</th>` found.

I'm assuming my look ahead has been incorrectly implemented. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
(?<=<th>).*(?=<\/th>)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HiL3Zi/1

Comment: Thanks for that Henry. It works perfectly, except that it needs to follow the html convention of allowing unlimited whitespace after the "th" (ie </th      >). I can easily account for that in the second group of your regex, but can't in the first due to the non-fixed width look-behind. Any idea how to get around that issue? Thanks again!

Comment: Analyzing yours, I'm thinking you might just need to make the regex "greedy" instead of "lazy": `<th\s*>([\S\s]*)<\/th\s*>(?!(?:<\/th\s*>))`
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HiL3Zi/2